# Python - opposite of __contains__

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

**GENERAL QUESTION**

I was wondering if there exists a Python opposite to `__contains__` (i.e., something like `__notcontains__`).

**MY EXAMPLE**

I need it for the following piece of code:

```
df_1 = df[(df.id1 != id1_array) | (df.id2.apply(id2_array.__contains__)]
df_2 = df[(df.id1 == id1_array) & (df.id2.apply(id2_array.__notcontains__)]
```

In other words, in `df1` I want only observations for which `id1` *is not in* `id1_array1` **or** `id2` *is in* `id2_array`, while for `df2` I want only observations for which `id1` *is in* `id1_array` **and** `id2` *is not in* `id2_array`.

Who can help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `not in`? `something.__contains__(some_other_thing) is False`?

Comment: Sorry are you asking about `df_1 = df[(df.id1 != id1_array) | (~df.id2.isin(id2_array)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer how to do this in pure pandas you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and use the negation operator `~` to invert the boolean series:

```
df_1 = df[(df.id1 != id1_array) | (df.id2.isin(id2_array)]
df_2 = df[(df.id1 == id1_array) & (~df.id2.isin(id2_array)]
```

This will be faster than using `apply` on a larger dataset as `isin` is vectorised

When using the comparison operators such as `==` and `!=` this will return `True/False` where the array values are same/different in the same position. If you are testing just for membership, i.e. does a list of values exist anywhere in the array then use `isin` this will also return a boolean series where matches are found, to invert the array use `~`.

Also as a general rule, avoid using `apply` unless it's not possible, the reason is that `apply` is just syntactic sugar to execute a `for` loop on the df and this isn't vectorised. There are usually ways to achieve the same result without using `apply` if you dig hard enough.

Comment: edit: Nevermind -- Also, apply is deprecated in 2.3+

Comment: @Samuel here `apply` is a `pandas.Series` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply so it's not a python specific method

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice he was using the pandas method, completely missed that tag all together

Comment: @Samuel although the OP is asking about the inverse of `__contains__` here they should use the built in `pandas` methods specific for this task as it's designed to do this quickly

Comment: @EdChum thanks for your answer. Maybe you can generalize your answer such that it can be of help for people with the same question as I had (see part general question in the original post)?

Comment: I've added a little more explanation, hope it makes things clearer

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I didn't notice this was using panda's specifically. My answer may not be accurate.

Generally, the magic functions (anything with __'s before and after) are not meant to be called directly. In this case, __contains__ is referenced by using the `in` keyword.

```
>>> a = ['b'] 
>>> 'b' in a 
True 
>>> 'b' not in a 
False
```

Comment: Not when you need to pass a callable which the OP is doing.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no `__notcontains__` method or similar. When using `x not in y`, the method `__contains__` is actually used, as shown bellow:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __contains__(self, x):
        print("__contains__ is called")
        return super().__contains__(x)

l = MyList([1, 2, 3])

1 in l
# __contains__ is called

1 not in l
# __contains__ is called
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the (very) late response. If what you're tryin' is to analize wether a character is or not in a string, you could check this out! It isn't very optimized but it might work :))

```
 while yourCharacter == False:
    stringVariable = str(input("text"))

    for characterPosition in range(0, len(stringVariable)):
        characterTest = stringVariable[characterPosition]
        if characterTest == "yourCharacter":
            yourCharacter = True
```

this (as you probably know), will able you to use the yourCharacter variable to check if the character is in the string or input.

I hope it helps somehow, and again, sorry for the late response :)

Answer (score 0):

opposite of `__contains___`

one way to use this as follows:

```
list.__contains__('ABC') #true if ABC is present in list

not list.__contains__('ABC') # false if ABC is present in list
```